# Get grand parent of childs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get grand parent `id` by clicking on every child, Used `event.target.parentNode.id` but it just return parent of current element, the goal is get `#HereIAm` id when you click on every childs. any idea?

```js
$(window).click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.parentNode.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="HereIAm">

  <ul>
    <li><a>click me</a></li>
    <li>click me</li>
  </ul>
  <span>click me</span>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the HTML, one option is to use `.closest` and use the selector string `div[id]` to select the nearest ancestor with an `id` attribute:

```js
$(document).click(function({ target }) {
  const closest = target.closest('div[id]');
  if (closest) console.log(closest.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="HereIAm">

  <ul>
    <li><a>click me</a></li>
    <li>click me</li>
  </ul>
  <span>click me</span>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Binding click event to window cause return error on clicking on white space

Comment: Thanks, have to check to see if the `closest` element exists first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **HereIAm** by taping **click me** you can simply access **parent of the parent of click me**

```js
function getGrandParent(target){
  if(target.parentElement.id === 'HereIAm'){
    console.log(target.parentElement.id)
  }else{
    getGrandParent(target.parentElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="HereIAm">

  <ul>
    <li onclick='getGrandParent(this)'><a>click me</a></li>
    <li onclick='getGrandParent(this)'>click me</li>
  </ul>
  <span onclick='getGrandParent(this)'>click me</span>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span onclick='getGrandParent(this)'>click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```